# I compiled the latest version of GCC. How to point CLion to its location?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clion

I have built the latest version of GCC in a directory. How do I point CLion to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I realized that what I need to configure is CMake. Since CLion has a bundled CMake, you can configure this inside CLion.

Go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake. Under CMake options, add

```
-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=...
```

and replace `...` with the path to `g++`.

There are other ways to do this, which are probably better. I just did this and it worked, but if you want to dig in some more, see here:

https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F